# reglas de acceso firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firestore

como puedo restringir en firestore que solo el usuario con un determinado email pueda leer/escribir en la base de datos?
De momento las reglas las tengo asi, de forma que todo el mundo puede acceder a la base de datos:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if (true);
    }
  }
}
```